# filtering Streambuilder/ listviewBuilder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, stream-builder

i am new to flutter and been trying to create a function that refresh the ListView.builder based on users choice.i am saving cities names as Strings inside my firestore documents in user collection.
i have multiple buttons that presents different cities and based on choice i need the ListView builder to rebuild. i have been struggling for a while trying to find the solution to this.
anyone here can help?

this is how i retrieve data from firestore

```
 StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('loading...');

               return Container(
                  width: 890.0,
                  height: 320.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 00.0),
                  child: new ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        User user = User.fromDoc(snapshot.data
                            .documents[index]);
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                          child: Container(
                              height: 300,
                              width: 300,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                              ),
                              child: _buildCard(user)),
                        );
                      }),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: what do you mean by based on choice?

Comment: hi @Henok , based on the button pressed. all my users have a field called myCity. and i would like to create buttons in my feedscreen that represent different cities. so based on the button pressed the listview.builder should return users from that city only.

Comment: there are multiple ways this could be solved, solution 1 is for static numbers of cities(if there are fixed amount of cities) create n StreamBuilders and we need to hide and show the widgets using IndexedStack, solution 2 is for dynamic amount of cities so we need to put the query in variable and change its state.

Comment: thanks @Henok . they both sound promising but i am not sure how to implement them. is it possible for you to direct me to a sample or tell me how i can accomplish this using this ways? i am using static numbers of cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote this code to show the implementation for static no of cities, clicking the buttons changes the index which then changes the texts(you will change them to stream builders with custom city streams), you can also scale it to dynamic list by manipulating the city list.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key,}) : super(key: key);
​
​
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
​
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int stackIndex = 0;
​
  final List<String> cities = ['Berlin', 'Denver', 'Nairobi', 'Tokyo', 'Rio'];
  
​
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children : [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.max,
          children : cities.map((city){
            return RaisedButton(
              child : Text(city),
              onPressed : (){
                setState((){
                  this.stackIndex = cities.indexOf(city);
                });
              }
            );
          }).toList()
          ),
          
          IndexedStack(
          index : stackIndex,
          children: cities.map((city){
            return yourStreamBuilder(city);
          }).toList()
        ),
        ])
      ),
     
    );
  }
  
  Widget yourStreamBuilder(String city){
    //you can use your custom stream here
    //Stream stream = Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('myCity', isEqualTo: city).snapshots();
​
​
    return Text(city);//replace this with your streamBuilder 
  }
}
​
```

Comment: thanks @Henok. i am trying to set it up but i am getting this error in console. flutter: type 'MappedListIterable<String, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: can you tell me at which line its throwing the error ?

Comment: i am not sure. sorry i am quite new. can i post my code here so you check out? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
 int stackIndex = 0;
 final List<String> cities =[
    'Stockholm',
    'Malmö',
    'Uppsala',
    'Västerås',
    'Örebro',
    'Linköping',
    'Helsingborg',
    'Jönköping',
    'Norrköping',
    'Lund',
    'Umeå',
    'Gävle',
    'Södertälje',
    'Borås',
    'Huddinge',
    'Eskilstuna',
    'Nacka',
    'Halmstad',
    'Sundsvall',
    'Södertälje',
    'Växjö',
    'Karlstad',
    'Haninge',
    'Kristianstad',
    'Kungsbacka',
    'Solna',
    'Järfälla',
    'Sollentuna',
    'Skellefteå',
    'Kalmar',
    'Varberg',
    'Östersund',
    'Trollhättan',
    'Uddevalla',
    'Nyköping',
    'Skövde',
  ];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.max,
              children: cities.map((city) {
                return OutlineButton(
                  child: Text(city),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      this.stackIndex = cities.indexOf(city);
                    });
                    },
                );
              }).toList()
            ),
            IndexedStack(
              index: stackIndex,
              children: cities.map((city){
                return myStreamBuilder(city);
              })
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myStreamBuilder(String city){
    Stream stream = Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('myCity', isEqualTo: city).snapshots();
    return Text(city);
  }
}
```

Comment: cities.map should be ending with .toList() that's what's causing the error

Comment: thank you @Henok , i missed that . now i am getting a new error saying type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'. thank you realy for taking time

Comment: anytime happy to help Rizzo , the new error does it show the line ?

Comment: thanks man @Henok  i am getting some lines with the error but could it be this at line 97?      When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _FeedScreenState.build (package:luncha/screen/feed_screen.dart:97:18)

Comment: @Henok i made it work by adding a <Widget> before map. now when i press the buttons it does navigate to the specifik user but dosent hide the the rest? thanks so much btw

Comment: does it show all users from the city thats clicked ?

Comment: i made it work now thanks to your help @Henok, you are awsome

Comment: you are very welcome rizzo glad I've been able to help

Comment: me again @Henok. do you know how i can return a 'No user' or 'loading' if there is no user in the particular city? thanks for everything btw

Comment: (snapshot.data.documents.length==0)?Text('loading ...") : ListView.builder .... and you dont have to thank me that much really, we are developer's community we help each other out thats what we do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216844/discussion-between-rizzo-moriarty-and-henok).